# Is there a more efficient alternative to executing a Stored Procedure in a loop?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures

I have a multitude of stored procedures being called from within webforms in my asp.net site and executed in loops. For the most part, this is fine, except when I'm working with higher quantities. Things get really slow. Is there an alternative I can try to make my site more efficient?

For example, I have a stored procedure `spReservePart` that does the following:

```
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @SparePartID int, @notes nvarchar(MAX), @sr int, @assignto nvarchar(MAX), @newloc nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    if (@sr = 0) begin set @sr = null end

    Insert into Reservations (ReservationID, StartDate, EndDate, SparePartID, Notes, Status, SRNumber, AssignedTo)
    Values (newid(), @startdate, @enddate, @SparePartID, @notes, 'Active', @sr, @assignto)

    Update MiddleMan Set ReservationID = (Select Top (1) ReservationID from Reservations where SparePartID=@SparePartID and Status = 'Active') where SparePartID=@SparePartID
    Update MiddleMan Set In_Use = 1 where SparePartID = @SparePartID
    Update MiddleMan Set SRHistory = (Select Top (1) SRNumber from Reservations where SparePartID=@SparePartID and Status = 'Active') where SparePartID = @SparePartID
    Update MiddleMan Set CurrentLocation = @newloc where SparePartID = @SparePartID

END
```

The webform it comes from has a Gridview with checkboxes, and for each checkbox selected it calls this stored procedure.

```cs
foreach (GridViewRow item in gvreserveparts.Rows)
                {//for each row in the gridview
                    var chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cbSelect");
                    if (chk.Checked == true) //checkbox is checked
                    {
                        //assignment of parameters here


                        //create connection with database
                        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionInfo);

                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        cmd.CommandText = "spReservePart";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", start);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", end);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SparePartID", sparepartid);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", notes);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sr", sr);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@assignto", assignto);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newloc", newloc);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }


                }
            }
```

For even 6 calls of this SP, it can take a long time. So a more efficient alternative would be very helpful.

Comment: You could use a table valued parameter and then redesign your procedure to be set based.

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: In my experience the fastest way of all is to use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert into a temporary table and then call a stored procedure to handle the inserts and updates as set operations. I have found this to be many times faster than using either table valued parameters or XML (which is another alternative).  As an unrelated point, why are you using `OleDbConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: @SMor while i wholeheartedly agree that using strongly typed parameters is preferable, the performance problem is not a big deal here because they are using a stored procedure. As such the datatype interpretation does not happen and caching isn't an issue because it is the procedure that is cached.

Comment: @SMor @Sean Lange Whilst I agree with both of you, I have never tested empirically, whether adding a strongly typed parameter is quicker than `AddWithValue`. I have always assumed it is. Have either of you actually checked?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock to answer your question, I inherited this code, and the previous authors used Oledb, and for the sake of consistency I also use Oledb.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of passing a single set of scalar valued parameters to the procedure, you could re-write your stored procedure to accept a table-valued parameter, and then you could pass all of your sets of parameters in a single table to the procedure and only execute it once.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a table valued parameter is a great option, but you can start by changing your procedure to avoid reading the Reservations table multiple times and updating the MiddleMan table 4 times. You can eliminate the reads using the OUTPUT clause and use a single UPDATE.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spReservePart 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime, @SparePartID int, @notes nvarchar(MAX), @sr int, @assignto nvarchar(MAX), @newloc nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Output TABLE(
        ReservationId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        SRNumber      INT,
        SparePartID   INT
    );

    IF (@sr = 0) 
        SET @sr = NULL;

    INSERT INTO Reservations (
        ReservationID, 
        StartDate, 
        EndDate, 
        SparePartID, 
        Notes, 
        Status, 
        SRNumber, 
        AssignedTo)
    OUTPUT  inserted.ReservationId, 
            inserted.SRNumber, 
            inserted.SparePartID 
    INTO @Output(
            ReservationId, 
            SRNumber, 
            SparePartID)
    VALUES (
        NEWID(), 
        @startdate, 
        @enddate, 
        @SparePartID, 
        @notes, 
        'Active', 
        @sr, 
        @assignto);

    UPDATE MiddleMan SET
        ReservationID   = o.ReservationID,
        In_Use          = 1,
        SRHistory       = o.SRNumber,
        CurrentLocation = @newloc
    FROM MiddleMan m
    JOIN @Output o ON m.SparePartID = o.SparePartID;
END
```

Comment: Would that this were true. It may well be what the OP intends, but `SELECT TOP (1)` without an `ORDER BY` is undefined. In my experience in such a case SQL Server delivers results in clustered index order, albeit that this is not guaranteed. I have just never seen a counter example.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to change your stored procedure to accept all of the data as a table.

The pass your data as dataTable to the stored procedure. So you will have to call the stored procedure once.

In this link, there is an example:

[How to send bulk data using table value parameters from c#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters)

This is how you should change your stored procedure to accept table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProcedure]
    (
     -- which accepts one table value parameter. 
     -- It should be noted that the parameter is read-only
     @Sample AS [dbo].[SampleDataType] READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Reservations (ReservationID, StartDate, EndDate, SparePartID, 
                              Notes, Status, SRNumber, AssignedTo)
        SELECT 
            ReservationID, StartDate,EndDate, ... 
        FROM
            @Sample
END
```

You can create a DataTable in your C# code and send it to the stored procedure as a parameter

```
var dataTable = new DataTable("SampleDataType"); 
//create column names as per the type in DB
dataTable.Columns.Add("startdate", typeof(DateTime)); 
dataTable.Columns.Add("enddate", typeof(DateTime));
dataTable.Columns.Add("SparePartID", typeof(Int32));  

//...
foreach (GridViewRow item in gvreserveparts.Rows)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cbSelect");

    if (chk.Checked == true) //checkbox is checked
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add("startDate", start); 
        dataTable.Rows.Add("endDate", end); 
//...
    }
}

var parameter = new SqlParameter(); 
//The parameter for the SP must be of SqlDbType.Structured 
parameter.ParameterName="@Sample"; 
parameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured; 
parameter.Value = dataTable; 

var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionInfo);
var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter); 

conn.Open();

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "spReservePart";

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```